# NavigationView throwing error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'menu' in package

Tags: android, material-design, drawerlayout, androiddesignsupport, navigationview

I am trying to add NavigationView in my layout as below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But the problem is I am getting an error during compile as below:

```
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Documents\Androidprojects\supporttest\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:(22) No resource identifier found for attribute 'menu' in package 'ranjithnair02.com.supporttest'
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Documents\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

I have added the menu item in menu/drawer.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha"
            android:title="First" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_2"
            android:icon="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material"
            android:title="Second" />
      </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: [https://pratamawijaya.com/programming/android-programming/after-google-io-2015-android-design-support-library-demo](https://pratamawijaya.com/programming/android-programming/after-google-io-2015-android-design-support-library-demo)

Comment: Did you add your Gradle dependency? `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project? Closing & opening Android Studio? That helped me.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct dependency to the Android Design Support Library.
It's easy to choose the wrong one - because it seems that Google posted two different dependency strings:

At the time of this answer, the [Android developer blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) (and the comment by  user hungryghost) had the correct dependency string, while the dependency string on the [Support library homepage](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#design) did not work.

Use this one:
`compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'`

Note that the version is 22.**2**.0 (wrong: <strike>22.0.0</strike>) and that the package is called *design* (wrong: <strike>support-design</strike>)

After these changes use the Android Studio menu "Rebuild project", or the "Sync" button that appears sometimes after changing the gradle file.
That finally made it work for me.

Comment: Wouldn't **com.android.support:appcompat-v7** include design lib?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Not according to maven (mvn dependency:tree) when used on a test project depending on appcompat-v7. Also, there is no indication of it on the support library website: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html

Answer (score 8):

Add the below line to app gradle file.

dependencies {
.....

- implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

....

}

for gradle version 3.0.1